# Problem with all ides an compilers using ttmath library (c++)

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I have created a program that factorizes, in prime numbers, a number received as input.
I tried to compile with dev c++ first and it gave me these errors:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `movq`
Error: incorrect register `%edx' used with `q' suffix
```

Netbeans throws this:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\Riemann\Riemann'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Release
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Frank/Desktop/Riemann/Riemann'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/Cygwin_1-Windows/riemann.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Frank/Desktop/Riemann/Riemann'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../../ttmath-0.9.3/ttmath/ttmathuint_x86_64_msvc.asm', needed by 'build/Release/Cygwin_1-Windows/_ext/88761bfc/ttmathuint_x86_64_msvc.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Frank/Desktop/Riemann/Riemann'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:60: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Frank/Desktop/Riemann/Riemann'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 657ms)
```

This is my source file:

```
#include "ttmath.h"
#include "sstream"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

//Prototipi:
string inttostr(ttmath::Int<1024*1024> toCast);
void FattorNumPrimi(ttmath::Int<1024*1024> n);

int main()
{
    ttmath::Int<1024*1024> n;
    cout<<"Choose your number: ";
    cin>>n; 
    FattorNumPrimi(n);
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Funzioni:
string inttostr(ttmath::Int<1024*1024> toCast)
{
    ostringstream converter;
    converter.seekp(0);
    converter <<toCast;
    return converter.str();
}

void FattorNumPrimi(ttmath::Int<1024*1024> n)
{
    string prec="This is your number's factorization: "+inttostr(1);
    //unsigned long long int i=0;
    //unsigned long long int j=0;
    int x;
        ttmath::Int<1024*1024> h=(1/2);//exponent for the pow function

        for (ttmath::Int<1024*1024> s=2; s<=n; s++)
        { 
           for (ttmath::Int<1024*1024> t=2; t*t<=s; t++)
           { x=0;
               if (s % t == 0)
               {
                   break;
                }else if (t+1 > s.Pow(h)) {

               while(x!=1)
               {   
                   if(n%2==0&&n!=0)//Added because the prime number generation skips 2 and 3
                   {
                      n=n/2;                  
                      prec=prec+" x "+inttostr(2);
                   }else if(n%3==0&&n!=0)//Added because the prime number generation skips 2 and 3
                   {
                      n=n/3;                  
                      prec=prec+" x "+inttostr(3);
                   }else if(n%s==0&&n!=0)//If n can be divided by the prime number
                   {
                      n=n/s;                  
                      prec=prec+" x "+inttostr(s);
                   if(n==s)//If n is equal to the current prime number
                   {
                      prec=prec+" x "+inttostr(n);
                      n=0;
                   }                                  
                   }else
                   {
                     x=1;
                   }     
               }
            }
        }
    }
        cout<<prec;
}
```

Visual studio doesn't compile too.

p.s.:The program works if I use unsigned long long int and I don't include the ttmath library, but I need it to work with huge numbers.

Comment: `ttmath::Int<1024*1024>` , really? I didnt fully understand how big those ints can be, but did you? It would take a user hours to type a number with that many digits...

Comment: Have you seen the faq section? "Which compiler can I use?

At the moment only two compilers are supported: GCC from 3.4 and Microsoft Visual C++ from 7.0. Another compilers were not tested. But if you're using this library on 64bit platforms you can only use GCC (Microsoft doesn't provide the inline assembler in its 64bit compiler). "

Comment: Yes, i read that, in Dev-c++ i'm using gcc 4.9.2 and it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Raise issues on the ttmath project issues list (after searching for duplicates), not here